# Getting Data From Another Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables:

> 1. Student(id(PK),name,subject_enrolled(FK)
> 2. Teacher(id(PK),name,subject_teaches(FK)
> 3. Subject(subject_code(PK),subject_name)
> 4. Combined(FIELDS not yet known)

By using MYSQL triggers, I want to insert data to the student table, it will automatically  get the names of the teacher table and place it to the `Combined` table based on the subject enrolled and the subject teaches. What is the best approach to realize that ?

Comment: What do you need the `Combined` table for?

Comment: i think u should try MYSQL Procedures it will help you

Comment: Combined(id,name1,name2,name3) from Teacher table sir. It is where i will know who are the teachers of the student based on his/her subjects.

Comment: MySQL Procedures? Ok, i'll search for it. Thanks sir! :)

Comment: you need to JOIN the table.... `select a.col1,b.col2 from table1 as a inner join table2 as b on a.col1=b.col1 where....`

Comment: you don't need separate table for combination tell us your requirement then we can provide the query

Comment: Ok thanks sir! I'm also thinking of it but how about i place it on a trigger? how can i resolve it's statement?

Comment: Sir, what do you mean in getting requirement? Thanks sir!

Comment: @jeeru data point you want to display or retrieve   ?? ex: I want to get all teacher names related to a Student .

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka, yes sir exactly! I want to get all teacher names related to a Student based on what the teacher's subject teaches and the student's subject enrolled. I hope i make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get it USING following query you don't need separate table and triggers

```
 SELECT ST.name as Student_name,T.name as Teacher_name ,S.subject as Subject ,S.subject_code as Subject_code  from Student ST
 inner join Subject S on S.subject_code=ST.subject_enrolled 
inner join Teacher T on T.subject_teaches=S.subject_code
 where ST.id=<your student id>
```

Comment: try this and let me know

Comment: Ok i will sir! Thank you so much :)